# How to make divs shrink to fit container maintaining their relative widths?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: rgb(36, 209, 13);
  height: 100px;
}

#one {
  width: 1000px;
}

#two {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

This is what it would look like without the shrinking.

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: rgb(36, 209, 13);
  height: 100px;
}

#one {
  width: 500px;
}

#two {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

This is with. What is the best approach to do this without manually adjusting the widths?  I tried to use flexbox with `flex-direction: column;` but it would not shrink with just one item per row. I also do not want to use `transform: scaleX(0.5);` or something like that. All of them should fit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would set the width the divs (one and two) as a percentage instead of a fixed value. That way they will always have its width relative to its container.

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: rgb(36, 209, 13);
  height: 100px;
}

#one {
  width: 100%;
}

#two {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know but I don't want to do that because I'd have to calculate the percentage manually in JS.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding your question correctly. Could you clarify what you mean by 'maintain their relative width'?

Answer (score 0):

Give the `container` `overflow:hidden`

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: rgb(36, 209, 13);
  height: 100px;
}

#one {
  width: 500px;
}

#two {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

And you should add this code to your CSS file before you start

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Overflow hidden does not do anything to scale the elements.